# How do I change a variable alternately in that C# code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
  void Update(){

      public int x = -10;

      if (Input.GetKey("w")){


        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(10, x);

      }
   }
```

> When I press the key w the variable x is -10, when I press another time w the variable x should be changed to 9. And when I press again "w" x should be -10 again. How do I do that in my code ?

Comment: Don't tag unrelated languages. Also show what you tried and where the problem is

Comment: You can use [XOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-). `0 ^ 1 == 1` then `1 ^ 1 == 0`. This `^ 1` will basically toggle back and forth

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code, just use [GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) inside the [Update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) function. You can also use a boolean or the modulus operator if you like a more compact code. Next time, please, remember to post your solution before asking for it.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PingPong: MonoBehaviour 
{
   private int counter = 0;

   void Update()
   {
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
      {
         if (counter == 0)
            counter = 1;
         else
            counter = 0;

         Debug.Log(counter);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: but in your code 1 and 0 are printed just two times. I want to have a loop where 1 and 0 are printed alternately.

Comment: The function [Update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) is called every frame, check the documentation for more. This is perfectly working.

Comment: Ok but how do I do this in my code at the top.